# How many items can the stackexchange global inbox contain?

Tags: support, global-inbox

Does the inbox have a maximum of announcements it can contain? Do very old announcements disappear get automatically deleted after a while?

Answer (score 5):

I counted 100 on the dropdown version on the top bar, which seems a nice neat number. Rather than being deleted, I suspect the last 100 items are retrieved.  You can check every single item that's ever been in your inbox in your network profile. I have somewhat over a thousand pages of replies, so I'm somewhat unsure if things get cleaned up but it's doubtful.

Empirically, deleted *comments* do go away though I need to science a bit more about other inbox contents to do with deleted posts. These however are not automatic, and there appears to be a short delay.

Comment: I have 2032 pages, with the last item being notification for the first comment I ever got, almost 11 years ago. So guess we can safely say it's not limited.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask yeah, me too.

Comment: I have 3379 pages of comments and counting...